# AngularJS controller function never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angularjs controller function is never called.  I see all the js files included in my sources, it's just not ever hitting the initialization of my controller.  What is wrong with this code?

eventListCtrl.js:

```
eventsApp.controller('eventListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // this code is never called
    alert('controller initializing');
    $scope.name = "Test";
}]);
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="eventListCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="spann11">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/eventListCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have `ng-app="eventsApp"` anywhere? And did you recreate `eventsApp` within your controller?

Comment: Agree with this comment. In case you forgot, put the `ng-app` outside the `<div ng-controller="...">`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to do this

```
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
```

So you actually activate the module

Comment: Doh, not sure how I missed this!

Answer (score 2):

I want to post my issue/resolution here in case anyone does the same thing as me.

```
<div ng-controller="coolCtrl" ng-if="VAR">
```

I was trying to init a controller on an element that didn't get created (because of the `ng-if="var"` )
*facepalm*

Comment: Thank you! I made the same mistake by adding ng-show on the controller wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

```
angular.module('eventsApp').controller('eventListCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // this code is never called
    alert('controller initializing');
    $scope.name = "Test";
}]);
```

in your controller file?

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking when I first saw the question. AngularJS is very trial-by-fire.

Comment: This would make no difference, It's identical to what he's doing already

Comment: the API on `module` is just very bad. Adding a second parameter makes it an initializer and people get confused.

Comment: @Connor not true. unless he made `eventsApp` global which would be very bad, in which case the answer still suggesting best practice.

Comment: @JoeMinichino it is global, as seen in the post :) and plus, in production it's likely to concatenate your files anyway, and it's not bad practice to have your namespace global

Comment: thanks for the comments on module api.  The code worked as is, just missing ng-app

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
<div ng-controller="eventListCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="spann11">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/controllers/eventListCtrl.js"></script>
</html>
```

This should fix it